# Qué hace realmente este codigo javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Encontré un pequeño trozo de código, quita una parte de un link al cargar la página (eso noté) pero me da miedo ponerlo en mi web ya que de pronto puede dañarla o quitarme de la busqueda de google... quiero entender bien qué es lo que hace y si todos los navegadores pueden leerlo, además de si existe peligro de tirarme la página

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var uri = window.location.toString(); 
    if (uri.indexOf("%3D","%3D") > 0) { 
        var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("%3D"));
        window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
    } 
    var uri = window.location.toString();
    if (uri.indexOf("%3D%3D","%3D%3D") > 0) {
        var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("%3D%3D"));
        window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
    } 
    var uri = window.location.toString(); 
    if (uri.indexOf("&m=0","&m=0") > 0) {
        var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("&m=0"));
        window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
    } 
    var uri = window.location.toString(); 
    if (uri.indexOf("?m=0","?m=0") > 0) {
        var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("?m=0")); 
        window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Agrega una breve descripción de tus esfuerzos de búsqueda/investigación como se sugiere en [ask]. Punto y aparte de esto, está muy bien que antes de utilizar un código que encontraste dediques tiempo a entenderlo. Lo primero sería que consultaras una fuente confiable como lo sería un libro o especificación. En el caso de JavaScript podrías recurrir también a Mozilla Developers Network (https://developer.mozilla.org) que tiene tanto material de autoaprendizaje para el que sabe muy poco o nada de programación como material de referencia que explica cad sentencia, tipo de objeto, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prácticamente el código esta limpiado la url de tu pagina de ""%3D", "%3D%3D", "&m=0", "?m=0" y cambiando la entrada del historial con la url limpia.

Si quieres revisar mas información puedes consultar: [Añadiendo y modificando entradas del historial](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/Manipulando_el_historial_del_navegador)